# Request.QueryString syntax

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have question regarding ASP.NET issue. Recently I migrated website from 32bit IIS to 64 bit IIS which is working in 32 bit mode.

There is web form that authenticates users. But here the issue I have: when I press submit button, in Chrome-based browsers it works well. In other browsers like Safari, IE it returns 404 error.

When I checked HTML code in safari, I see that form action set to:

```
<form action="/script.asp" ...>
```

When I check script.asp on the server, I see that form action set to:

```
<FORM action="<%=MM_LoginAction%>"...>
```

At the beginning of script I can see

```
MM_LoginAction = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
If Request.QueryString <> "" Then MM_LoginAction = MM_LoginAction + "?" + Request.QueryString
```

So as I am understanding, "IF" part of this code isn't executed? Could you lease help me with that?

UPD: in Chrome form action also set to "/script.asp" but it works well. Is that browser compatibility problem?

Comment: Have you cleared the Chrome browsers cache and refreshed the page?

Comment: i don't see any asp.net here?

Comment: @WorkSmarter yes, I've cleared, it had nothing to do with code syntax, just cross-domain iframe issues.